# Is there a way to expand the cube of a trinomial easily?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> Is there a way to expand $(x+y+z)^3$ easily/fast?

It takes some time for me to expand this type of quantities, I was just thinking if there's like a shortcut.

Motivation:  whenever I do $u$-substitutions in my integral calculus, my professor always wants me to expand it and I'm having problems when the final answer is like $\frac{1}{3} (x^3+2x+3)^3$, it consumes my time.

Comment: What do you mean by fast? in nanoseconds?

Comment: Using combinatorics is the best way.

Answer (score 6):

In $(x+y+z)^n$, the coefficient of $x^ay^bz^c$, where $a+b+c=n$, is $\frac{n!}{a!b!c!}$.

Explain: For each $x^ay^bz^c$ you choose a of "x", b of "y", c of "z" in each of $(x+y+z)$, therefore you have $C^n_aC^{n-a}_bC^{n-a-b}_c=\frac{n!}{a!b!c!}$ many ways to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use $(a+b+c)^3=\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3+3a^2b+3a^2c+2abc)$.

Answer (score 3):

If $z=0$ you get $x^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+y^3$. All terms will have degree $3$ so all terms which contain only two of $x, y,z$ will be of the form $a^3$ or $3ab^2$ so the terms including $z$ can be written down (all forms appear by symmetry).

Then there is one term $xyz$ which  is not of this form. You can take any letter from the first bracket, one of two from the second and the third is forced. This gives a coefficient of $6$.

If expanding $(a+b+c+d)^3$ note that terms have at most three letters, so the forms of the terms and the coefficients can be determined by expanding $(a+b+c)^3$ and then adding the symmetrically equivalent terms involving $d$.

Answer (score 0):

This identity is fairly well known, and straight-forward to verify from sight:

$(a+b+c)^3 = a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + 3(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ac) - 3abc$

Note that the term count nets out correctly as 3 + 27 - 3 = 27; and the cardinality of the terms originating from the complex product are correct.